# "this" is "undefined" in apollo query (vue + nuxt)

Tags: vue.js, graphql, vue-apollo

I'm using GraphQL (Symfony + API Platform) with Vue Apollo and Nuxt.

I have a detail page for an issue and want to load the specific issue, but I always get `Cannot read property 'issueId' of undefined` because `this` is `undefined`. This is the relevant script part of my Page

```
<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      issueId: null
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.issueId = this.$route.params.id
  },
  apollo: {
    issue: {
      query: gql`
        query($issueId: ID!) {
          issue(id: $issueId) {
            id
            description
          }
        }
      `,
      variables: {
        issueId: this.issueId
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I set issueId to `issues/3`, it works

```
variables: {
    issueId: 'issues/3'
}
```

Comment: `this` won't point to the vue instance, when you reference it outside of a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution

As described [here](https://apollo.vuejs.org/api/smart-query.html#options), if just have to turn

```
variables: {
  issueId: this.issueId
}
```

into

```
variables() {
  return {
    issueId: this.issueId
  }
}
```

But I don't understand the difference

Answer (score 0):

Use `console.log()` in `created` to check values ...

... probably (not working with vue for years) there should be `$route.params.id` alone, without `this` ...

... you can use this value directly in `variables`